# if logical statment is NO, change cell colour

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

if sum of e2,f2 does != d2, change text to NO. 
This works,
I now want to change the colour of the text box to red,

please advise

```
=IF(D2=SUM(E2,F2),"Yes","NO")
```

Comment: You will need to use Conditional Formatting.

Comment: could you give me an example please?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-FED60DFA-1D3F-4E13-9ECB-F1951FF89D7F

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells you want to apply the formatting to.

On the "Home" ribbon, go to "Conditional Formatting" and add a "New Rule".

Select "Format cells that contain".

Select "Cell Value", "Equal To", And enter "NO"

Now click "Format", on the "Fill" tab, select a red colour.

Click OK. Click OK again.

The cells you selected should now be coloured Red if they contain "NO", as per your formula.

Comment: yeah got it...but seeing no one else answers...points go to you my man...thanks